# Login with adminInitiateAuth using email and password in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Currently I am developing a custom login flow for some of my projects, using AWS Cognito.

Recently I achieved the login using username and password, as follows:

```
const data: CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.Types.AdminInitiateAuthRequest = {
    UserPoolId,
    AuthFlow: "ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    ClientId: CognitoConfig.ClientId,
    AuthParameters: {
        USERNAME: username,
        PASSWORD: password,
        // SECRET_HASH: hash,
    }
};
```

Is it possible to login using **email+password** using *CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminInitiateAuth*?

Ive tried to replace **USERNAME** with **EMAIL** (and the respective field value), but I got an **InvalidParameterException**, expecting **USERNAME** to be forwarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass the email in USERNAME attribute, Also set the AuthFlow to "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH"

```
const data: CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.Types.AdminInitiateAuthRequest = {
    UserPoolId,
    AuthFlow: "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH",
    ClientId: CognitoConfig.ClientId,
    AuthParameters: {
        USERNAME: 'xyz@example.com',
        PASSWORD: password,
        // SECRET_HASH: hash,
    }
};
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminInitiateAuth.html

Comment: Thanks, it worked, It was necessary to change the authentication flow in the user pool from USERNAME(it was USERNAME + verified email, but i was not using the email verification to do so) to EMAIL